# error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

First time using firestore and I'm getting this error. It seems to be a problem with Ivy, from my research. I don't have a lot of experience modifying tsconfig.app.json, which is the direction I've been pointed to, following other answers.

The only thing I was able to modify from the original project was to use Angular Fire 6 instead of 5, which I had done initially to follow a tutorial.

Here's package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "language",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.1",
    "firebase": "^7.8.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.0-0 || ^0.900.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.12.1",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "language": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/language",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "language:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "language:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "language:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "language:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "language:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "language"
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
  
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: restarting console helped me

Comment: Dup component incorrectly nested in multiple modules. Asked for better error descrip: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40616

Comment: This error also occurs when you miss @ before NgModule

Comment: Pablo, point `1.` in [Venkata Thrivedi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984571/16269129) below is the only thing required for this specific error message. unfortunately, the `package.json`, `angular.json`, and `tsconfig.app.json` files you posted actually don't matter _in this case_...

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Your module is not yet loaded by the Angular Server in `node` `ng serve`, so restart your server so the server loads the module that you just added in `@NgModule app.module.ts`

Look at [jejakhacker.com](https://jejakhacker.com)

Comment: I've been finding out that many times restarting the server or restarting IDE will do the trick :D

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting the issues with the mono-repo workspace.Where it has root node_modules.

Comment: I'm still finding that I _swear_ I've restarted since I made a change like this, but... turns out I didn't and restarting fixed it.  Thanks for reminding me that I need to "turn it off and on again" before even googling!

Comment: Yeah. I was getting this error in core.module with Angular 11. When i run "ng serve" error gone.

Comment: You would need to restart VSCode in order for Angular Language Service to recompile the packages.

Comment: Actually angular should provide a hint in the error log itself to restart and check!

Comment: Restarting the terminal had done the trick in Angular10.

Comment: Ctrl+C => Y && npm start in VS Code terminal. Worked for Angular 12!

Comment: Thank you! Simple but worked for me.

VS Code Reload: F1 > Type Reload Window > Press Return

Thanks again.

Comment: Or you did not safe a file after moving it the file into another directory/changing it.

Answer (score 164):

This error shows when you add component declaration in `imports: []` instead of `declarations: []`, e.g:

```
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  SomeComponent <-----------wrong
],
```

Comment: This! Also check other declaration properties too, such as `providers`, etc. Make sure they all have correct and valid values set.

Answer (score 81):

I got this error when I made the bonehead mistake of importing `MatSnackBar` instead of `MatSnackBarModule` in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Fellow Bonehead here - MatCheckboxModule - Your answer was useful, thanks

Comment: Training material is great, but you really learn by doing :)

Comment: The same thing happened for me with HttpClient. Updated HttpClient to HttpClientModule in my app.module.ts and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I signed in for the the first time in years just to say Thanks ;)

Comment: sigh...MatAutocompleteModule - I don't know how long it would have taken me to realize without your comment, thank you.

Comment: But I am getting below error on doing this, ```Property 'open' does not exist on type 'MatSnackBarModule'.``` Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe `open` is a method on `MatSnackBar`, not `MatSnackBarModule`, but you would probably get better responses by posting that as its own question.

Answer (score 29):

**I made a mistake by adding a `service` into `imports` array instead of `providers` array.**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyService // wrong here
  ],
  providers: [
    MyService // should add here
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`Angular` says you need to add `Injectables` into `providers` array.

Comment: Totally agree with this.  In my case with ng12, I switched from using ngx-clipboard to the now "built-into-angular" @angular/cdk/clipboard.  I imported ClipboardModule correctly, but the "Clipboard" export is actually a service.  Removing it from Exports and placing in Providers did the trick for me.

Answer (score 19):

Fixed it by opting out of Ivy as per documentation.

https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Change tsconfig.app.json to opt out of Ivy.

```
"enableIvy": false
```

Comment: Folks, disabling Ivy which will soon to be the ONLY rendering engine for Angular is not the way to go. I understand if you're needing to push to `prod` ASAP because of reasons but you should diagnose and find out what is really causing your issue.

Comment: @AaronJordan I think the issue is moreso that Ivy is *not* production-ready, contrary to what the Angular team says. A production-ready upgrade should not have *near* the amount of bugs that Ivy has. Also, View Engine is not going away anytime soon for backwards-compatibility reasons (same reason why Angular library builds still happen in View Engine, not Ivy)

Comment: @u Ah...I don't see Ivy has a lot of bugs. Where is your reference?

Comment: In most instances @AaronJordan is right. However I've found that disabling Ivy is more stable when developing local libraries and hot loading into another project. Related answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61527483/212700](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61527483/212700)

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes when you change/update **@NgModule** in your project, projects get compiled but changes doesn't get reflect. So, restart once to get expected results if you not get it.
**ng serve**

Comment: saved me a bunch of wasted time thank you. should have known this by now.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

1) Stop the ng server

2) Reinstall your package

```
npm install your-package-name
```

3) Run all again

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 8):

try to clear cache

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm install`

Comment: It seems like correct command is `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 8):

My mistake: I was missing the `Module` part, I wrote

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

instead of

```
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

in my module.

Answer (score 6):

For me I was working under Ubuntu

The error disappeared if I use **sudo** with **ng**

```
sudo ng build
sudo ng serve
```

A better solution is to grant the current user the needed permissions on the current folder using the following command:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ./
```

Doing so will let you run ng commands without sudo.

Comment: this answer helped me to resolve my issues

Comment: It is likely you have installed something as root.   It maybe time to check out the project again using the user account and building it there.

Issue with using root is you may install a bad npm package by accident and end up with a hacked system.

see answer by Shankar Ganesh for how to reset security.

Comment: works as same here project created using root

Answer (score 6):

This can also occur when using the wrong import (for example when using autoimport). let's take the MatTimePickerModule as an example. This will give an error message that is similar to the one described in the question:

```
import { NgxMatTimepickerModule } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker/lib/timepicker.module';
```

This should instead be

```
import { NgxMatTimepickerModule } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';
```

Comment: Just my one cent. The file had imports as `import { MatFormField, MatHint, MatLabel } from '@angular/material/form-field';`. It should be instead `import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';` 


**When imports are wrong, then also the same error occurs**. It took me 1hr. I almost was about to disable Ivy. **I was using Angular version 11**

Answer (score 6):

In my case I got this solved by setting "strictTemplates" back to *false* in `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

I had previously set this to *true* to prevent a VStudio pop-up from showing:

[image]

Comment: Worked for me thanks, despite being in pre-ivy version: angular8

Comment: For me this just hid the error and made it compile but the website didn't work, it didn't render the component.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

1. Stop the ng server(ctrl+c)
2. Run Again

   ```
   npm start / ng serve --open
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This issue will be fixed by adding the `postinstall` script below in your `package.json`.

It will be run after a npm install.

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "ngcc"
}
```

Post adding the above code, run `npm install`

This works for me when upgrading to Angular 9+

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue in Ubuntu because the Angular app directory was having `root` permission. Changing the ownership to the local user solved the issue for me.

```
$ sudo -i
$ chown -R <username>:<group> <ANGULAR_APP>
$ exit 
$ cd <ANGULAR_APP>
$ ng serve
```

Comment: Wow you've saved my day! My Angular code was in Docker and all the files belonged to "root". Angular couldn't access a file, and gave me this cryptic error!

Comment: @kolypto How would you change the ownership to the local user? I am using windows, and in the "properties>security>advanced" of the app folder did not find any such option. Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

I was importing `mat-list`.  My mistake was using the following:

```
import { MatList } from "@angular/material/list";
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatList,
  ]
})
```

I forgot to append 'Module' suffix to the import and export declaration.  The following fixed the problem:

```
import { MatListModule } from "@angular/material/list";
@NgModule({
  exports: [        
    MatListModule, // <-- Add 'Module' suffix here!
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was matching the version of angular material & adapter to the lowest version of another angular module. Then reinstalled & re-ran.

```
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "10.1.2",
```

As you can see my cdk was 10.2.1, and my material was also 10.2.1.
I saw the lowest version used was 10.1.2, so i changed the versions:

```
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.2", (was 10.2.1)
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.1.2", (was 10.2.1)
```

to 10.1.2, ran "npm install" and then "ng serve", and it compiled successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I faced issue on Angular 12 and the issue is my colleague defined the component in page module and as well as the common module we use globally in project.

Removed from globally file module, issue resolved.

`On My Case`

Answer (score 1):

Work for me

angular.json

```
"aot": false
```

Answer (score 1):

i simply change my import from import from `{ AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';`
to
`import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`

and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

### It also happens when you import some mat components which is not used anywhere in your components.

- if you have all mat components imported in you `app.module.ts` you have imported some mat components and you have not used any of the components in imports and exports arrays in `app.module.ts` means no issues no errors will throw works fine.
- if you create feature module for that let say by `ng g m material` this will create `material.module.ts` filename.
- now we have to copy all mat import statements to newly created feature module
  before copying keep in mind is any import statements grayed out or not(some indication IDE shows this name is not used). if grayed out  means you have to remove those names then copy and paste it to `MaterialModule` imports and exports array. that's solve.

Answer (score 1):

1. App.Module.ts

   You can solve the error by adding the injectables in **Provider not imports or declarations.**
2. Inside Service.ts

   Add **@injectable** over the class

ex:

```
@Injectable()
 export class WebApiService {   }
```

even if you give space might not work

ex:

```
@Injectable()


export class WebApiService {    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If
you run `npm install` or `yarn install` with root account
and
run `ng serve` with a non-root account,
you will encounter this issue.

Workaround:
**start server with root account as well**

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to add a custom pipe to my shared module and I've added it in import and export. That's why it caused this issue.

I solved this issue by adding my custom pipe into declarations:[], exports:[] and providers:[].

I solved this issue by following code :

```
@NgModule({

 declarations: [
   myCustomPipe,
 ],

 exports: [
   myCustomPipe,
 ],

 providers: [
  myCustomPipe,
 ]

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the only way I could solve it was to:

1. Import the module instead of the component
2. Match the folder name /my-component-y/ with MyComponentY.ts, I had /component-y/ and MyComponentY.ts

The root components are lazy loaded since it's for a mulitsite if that makes any difference.

Best solution is to use React/Next.js instead though of this old hacky framework.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of all the anwers here helped on my side.

Short version: Remove the ".angular" (caching) folder in project root!

Long version:
The NG6002 error came up in nearly every NgModule. It was consequential error because one of my directive (class CustomRouterLink extends RouterLink {}) had invalid injection tokens.

I fixed the injection token mistake, but angular still compained 100+ of the NG6002 errors. After hours of trying out all findings in the www, I just removed the ".angular" (caching) folder in project root, restartet the angular dev server.. TADAAA everything working again.

Comment: I don't know what good the .angular folder does - my angular doesn't build faster or anything and I've not noticed any improvement in behavior (other than symlinks seem to be more robust). I'd say the decision to create this angular cache causes a lot more problems than it fixed and, at least, should be made optional.

Answer (score 0):

`npm cache clean --force` -> cleaning the cache maybe solve the issue.

Comment: its not related to cache, The issue is NgModule and providing in a wrong collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested all the answers here but non of them worked for me. So I decided to change `angular.js` file. there is a `aot` option there which is true. then I altered that to the false and the error vanished!

```
"options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/DateMeUI",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false, // here you have to change
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

However, I got that there is 'tsconfig.app.json' which I couldn't find that in my project(maybe you have to add this manually ) by this file you can set the `"enableIvy": false` as others mention to it. [tsconfig.app.json](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

Comment: setting an aot to false,  it is likely problem will occur in production.   This is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your tsconfig.app.json in your project and remove all from it

and copy below code and paste it. It will solve your issue :)

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
  },

  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was calling `.forRoot()` from some child modules that were meant to be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while making a shared directive. Now Initially it got into declarations array of the app module (by default after I ran command with cli).

I had it into shared module `declarations array` and `exports array`. Now as soon as I removed it from `app.module.ts` file the issue got resolved.

The issue was it was declared inside 2 modules (shared and app.module). Removed from the app.module and voila!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was with the latest node. I was dockerizing the Angular app and using the latest node version like `FROM node:latest as build`

To make it work use Angular supported node versions like `FROM node:14.17.4`

Answer (score 0):

it can be occurs when you import a module that you already installed, but one ore more of its dependencies are missing

Answer (score 0):

restart visual studio code so Angular Language Service to recompile the packages

Answer (score 0):

Removing the node_modules, clearing the npm cache and reinstalling the node_modules again fixed this issue for me.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean -f
npm i
```