# Angular 12 migration issue error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

Tags: angular, migration

We are migrating our project to angular 12 and primeng 12, but we are stuck in this error that repeat it many times.
We looked at other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res) but couldn´t resolve with any of the solutions proposed on the answers.

When do ng build it shows this error:

```
Error: src/app/app-shared.module.ts:117:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

export class AppSharedModule {}
```

and is followed by many repeated errors in the same location.

[image]

We already tried many solutions like do ng server, deactivate Ivy, but none of them solved.

Is there any solution for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, we came to a conclusion that we made a mistake trying to migrate our project from angular 10 to 12 and prime ng 9 to 12.

**When migrating an angular project, is not recomended upgrade multiple versions at the same time**

As angular recomends in https://angular.io/guide/updating

So,now will make the migration step by step, first preparing the application,  by removing all warnings and deprecated, and then migrating one version at a time.

Thanks!

Edit: After restart migration this error appears aggain after set  `"enableIvy": true` as one of our modules is not compatible with ivy, setting to false solve the problem

Comment: i just tried to put the phrase on red alert style but i dont know to make it ;(

Comment: Also doing `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json ; npm install ;` between every `ng update` call helps with some issues during such update spree.

Comment: what this command does? Here we used to delete node modules package.lock and do npm install again, to clean and restart project

Comment: Exactly that. My point is that outcome of consequtive `ng update` when going 9-10-11-12 is different if you don't reinstall from scratch between versions.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem because one of the modules had a *bundled* package files inside. Had to remove it and add a proper `package.json` reference.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your answer?