# Problem with imports/exports/declarations component in Angular

Tags: angular, import, components

I have a component created, as you can see in the code sample, I import it, export it and even declare it, but it doesn't take me. Can you please tell me what the problem may be?

Error:
*Appears in the NgModule.imports of SalesModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
9 export class PaymentStatusComponent implements OnInit {*

sales.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [PaymentStatusComponent],
    imports: [PaymentStatusComponent],
    declarations: [PaymentStatusComponent]
})
export class SalesModule {}
```

Comment: Remove the component from the import and let me know if that fixed it.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to import something you're declaring and exporting...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res)

Comment: Easy mistake to make. No probs.

Comment: @jburtondev Yes, thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully this is a simple fix.

**Remove** `PaymentStatusComponent` from the `imports` array.

**Why?**
Because it's a component and the `imports` array only takes modules.