# error : Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, typescript, router, angular-activatedroute

I had this message when I've tried to ng serve, and I don't know what this means and what I should do, someone can help?

> Error: node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:54:22 - `error NG6002`:
> Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be
> resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares
> ActivatedRoute has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not
> compatible  with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library
> is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the
> library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible
> with Ivy.
>
> export declare class ActivatedRoute {

that is my `router.d.ts` file :

> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
> export declare classActivatedRoute {

> ```
> url: Observable<UrlSegment[]>;
> params: Observable<Params>;
> queryParams: Observable<Params>;
> fragment: Observable<string>;
> data: Observable<Data>;
> outlet: string;
> component: Type<any> | string | null;
> snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
> get routeConfig(): Route | null;
> get root(): ActivatedRoute;
>
> get parent(): ActivatedRoute | null;
> get firstChild(): ActivatedRoute | null;
> get children(): ActivatedRoute[];
> get pathFromRoot(): ActivatedRoute[];
> get paramMap(): Observable<ParamMap>;
> get queryParamMap(): Observable<ParamMap>;
> toString(): string; }
> ```

that is   app.module.ts file

```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
> import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

> import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 
> import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
> import { FooterComponent } from'./footer/footer.component'; 
>import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component'; 
>import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
> import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';
> import { SideBarComponent } from './side-bar/side-bar.component';
> import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
> import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
> import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
> import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
> import { ContactsComponent } from'./contacts/contacts.component';
> import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
> import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
> import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
> import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details/product-details.component';
> import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

> @NgModule({   declarations: [
>     AppComponent,
>     FooterComponent,
>     NavbarComponent,
>     ProductsComponent,
>     ProductListComponent,
>     SideBarComponent,
>     UserComponent,
>     HomeComponent,
>     LoginComponent,
>     CartComponent,
>     ContactsComponent,
>     PageNotFoundComponent,
>     SignupComponent,
>     ProductDetailsComponent,   ], 
>  imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     AppRoutingModule,
>     FormsModule,
>     ReactiveFormsModule,
>     ActivatedRoute,
>     HttpClientModule,   ],   
>providers: [],  
> bootstrap: [AppComponent] })
```

> export class AppModule { }

Comment: could you include more code in your question? specifically the `app.module.ts file?` most likely the error comes from how you are doing the imports of your modules or components

Comment: i don't see any error in your imports but this could help since there could be multiple scenarios https://stackoverflow.com/a/69793983/4957620

Answer (score 1):

Activated Route is not a module, it is a service.
You have to remove from the imports.
You can use it anyway as you're already adding a routing module.