# Angular 12, Typescript 4.2 :error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of PeriscopePrototypeModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded my app from Angular 11 to 12, and to typescript 4.2.4. When I do ng serve, app fails to compile with the error :

```
Error: src/app/SharedModule.ts:149:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of PrototypeModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?

149 export class SharedModule {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The SharedModule code is as follows :

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClarityModule, ClrFormsNextModule } from '@clr/angular';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { MaterialModule } from './material'

@NgModule({
    imports: [//list of imports]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

I have no leads as to what might be causing the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res)

Comment: @Nick, I did come across this post, and I tried some of these solutions proposed. But none of them worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure that all of the dependencies are updated? Updating angular will update also it's dependencies but not the dependencies' dependencies (sorry for my poor language, i'm not english as you may have understood). This can cause this problem tho

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Any solutions you found @SaiKrishna