# 'NgxsRootModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngxs

I am trying to learn NGXS and, therefore, following a tutorial. The tutorial said to install ngxs store and other dependencies, and I did with:

```
npm install @ngxs/store --save; 
npm i @ngxs/logger-plugin --save; 
npm i @ngxs/devtools-plugin --save-dev
```

But after doing that, my code will not work and says there is a problem with my app.module.ts:

'NgxsRootModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
'NgxsLoggerPluginModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
'NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';
import { NgxsLoggerPluginModule } from '@ngxs/logger-plugin';
import { NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule } from '@ngxs/devtools-plugin';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]), NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(), NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Does anyone have any idea on how this could be solved, please? I tried a lot of things already, such as restarting VSCode and deleting node_modules and running npm i again, to no results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share some error logs, so we can help you? A good attempt would be to try to reproduce this in a sandbox and compare.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in Angular 15.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on a different stackoverflow post:

[error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res)

"Your module is not yet loaded by the Angular Server in `node` `ng serve`, so restart your server so the server loads the module that you just added in `@NgModule` `app.module.ts`"

So you just need to start the project with the imports and without implementation. And then you can add them in the `@NgModule`.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular/core 15.2.2 there was a breaking change that the NGXS team was aware of, but thought wasn't coming until Angular 16.  [It centered around NGCC and eivyEnabled](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1974)

They currently have a fix for the issue, but it is [still pending merge and release in the next V3.Minor-Version](https://github.com/ngxs/store/milestone/15).

An immediate work around is to either downgrade Angular version to 15.0 or [install the @dev branch version of NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/getting-started/installation#development-builds) until the next release of V3 linked above (as of 03.18.2023)

```
npm install @ngxs/store@dev --save
```

Doing the above, I currently have it working with the following:

```
"@angular/core": "^15.2.2"
"@ngxs/store": "^3.7.6-dev.master-4d7e301"
```