# why am i getting NG 6002 error in all my the modules d. This is happening after upgrading to angular from v11 to v12

Tags: angular

This is happening in all the modules.

I tried uninstalling node modules, reinstalling node modules, clear cache but i could not able to resolve it.

I installed whatever the packages required for upgrading from angular 11 to angular 12. made all the changes provided in the angular update guide

Comment: Does any of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res) help?

Comment: `https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0` Please refer this link, may be it will help.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal tried all the steps provided in that link. is there any way to resolve NG6002 issue?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot for error? You also need to update the versions of the current packages for compatibility with the updated version of Angular.